# How can I create a Uninstall/Wait/Install Command Sequence in a Powershell Script?

Tags: powershell, deployment

How can I have powershell run the silent uninstall first, wait until it is finished, and then run the install? After researching I did as below, which works, but the blank Notepad window pops up and I had to close it.

I don't want the user to get any notepad window when I deploy this to them, simply uninstall and then install.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "On-Screen Takeoff"} | foreach-
object -process {$_.Uninstall()} 

Notepad.exe | Out-Null

$arguments="/quiet"
Start-Process "\\davisconstruction.com\ROOT\Installs\OnCenter\OST\Testverion3906\ost3906.msi" $arguments
```

Comment: What is the point of calling notepad?

Answer (score 0):

I use [uninstallw](http://www.tarma.com/support/uninstall.htm) for this task, then I can easily

```
start-process  -path $Path -arguments $arguments -wait
```

-wait is what you're looking for, functions just like `start "" /wait ....` in batch does.

Comment: Just so I understand, I would take out Notepad.exe | Out-Null and instead I would just use -wait after my 1st script when I run the whole thing? thanks

Comment: Yeah, I don't see what running notepad accomplishes, so I would remove it. Basically, you would run `start-process -path $PathToUninstallw -arguments $UninstallwArguments  -wait' for the uninstall, then another `start-process` for the installer, again with `-wait`.

Comment: I'm all set I was able to call a batch uninstall file pause for about 30 seconds and then run the uninstall.  This is thanks to some other forums and feedback from other folks. All this ran silently so I am set thank you for your feedback. 

Start-process "<path>"
Start-Sleep -Seconds <#>
$arguments="/quiet"
Start-process "<path>"$arguments